# ElasticSearch, custom analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using a custom analyzer like

```
            'no_analyzer': {
              "type":"custom",
              "tokenizer": "keyword",
              "filter": ["lowercase"]
            },
```

I want to have a exact query search, but it fails if search term has a space and returns no results.

Comment: could you show an example of the query?